# Combining two regular expression

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have these two regular expression ,tried combining .But not working

```
Dim regExCheckLength As Regex = New Regex("^\w{10}$")
Dim regexCheckFormat As Regex = New Regex("\b(SSN|TC|EMP)")
```

I am new to reg ex,is there a way to combine

Comment: Combine in what way? Do you want to detect strings which match both of these patterns (AND), or either one of them (OR)?

Comment: Have to satisfy both(AND)

Comment: @AvinashRaj-thanks boss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use logical OR operator to combine both regexes.

```
Dim regExCheckLength As Regex = New Regex("^\w{10}$|\b(SSN|TC|EMP)")
```

To satisfy both, you need to use a positive lookahead like below,

```
Dim regExCheckLength As Regex = New Regex("^(?=\w{10}$).*\b(SSN|TC|EMP).*")
```